# How to get statistical temperature from WHAM?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, statistical-thermodynamics, free-energy

I ran a series of replica exchange molecular dynmaics for the different temperatures. I used WHAM to sample metastable states. From the results of WHAM, we can get probabilties ($p
$) from the energy distributions of the states, allowing to get free energy by $F=−\ln p$. But I want to have temperatures for the metastable states. Is there any fancy way to get temperatures? Any suggestions and questions about the problem are welcome.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future !!! You might also be interested in these related questions: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1659/5 , https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1942/5